# How to make a nested python dictionary based on level numbers

Tags: python

How can i build a nested python dictionary, based on **number** of levels, like this?

How can be the recursive function passing int of levels?

```
{
"aggs": {
      "cat_level_1": {
            "terms": {
                 "field": "cat_level_1"
            },
              "aggs": {
                  "cat_level_2": {
                      "terms": {
                            "field": "cat_level_2"
                           },
                            "aggs": {
                                 "cat_level_3": {
                                     "terms": {
                                          "field": "cat_level_3"
                                    }
                              }
                       }
                   }
             }
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be input and output?

Comment: input only integer of levels, output the dictionary you see

Comment: Where do values like `size: 1000` come from?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do this with a simple `for i in range(1, num_levels+1):` loop.

Comment: is difficult for me build the dictionary by nested keys not for looping

Answer (score 1):

We can build the dictionary from the deepest level, wrapping the previously built dictionary on each level.

```py
def dict_with_depth_of(n):
    return {
        "aggs": {
            f"cat_level_{n}": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": f"cat_level_{n}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

def nested_dict(n):
    d = None
    for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)):
        new_d = dict_with_depth_of(i)
        if d is not None:
            new_d["aggs"][f"cat_level_{i}"] = d
        d = new_d
    return d

print(nested_dict(3))
```

Output:

```
{'aggs': {'cat_level_1': {'aggs': {'cat_level_2': {'aggs': {'cat_level_3': {'terms': {'field': 'cat_level_3'}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: thanks, right approach.. the perfect script below

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer

```
def dict_with_depth_of(n):
    return {
        "aggs": {
            f"cat_level_{n}": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": f"cat_level_{n}"
                }
            }
        }
    }


def nested_dict(n):
    d = None
    for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)):
        new_d = dict_with_depth_of(i)
        if d is not None:
            new_d["aggs"][f"cat_level_{i}"].update(d)
        d = new_d
```